# How to get a div to extend out of a bootstrap container to the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to get a div within a container to extend to the edge of the page.

As you can see in my fiddle I have managed to do this, however the red 'bar' goes off the page so the user is able to scroll to the right.

I would like it to function how it does now but with the red div touching the side of the page and going no further.

Things to keep in mind:

- I am trying to keep it pure HTML/CSS for now,
- The code must be responsive,
- This will also be used in a CMS so any length of text could be added.

```css
.container{
  background-color:grey;
}

.row{
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-bottom:40px;
}

.row_outer{
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  display: block;
  float:right; 
  clear:both;
}

.text{
  display: inline-block;
}

.holder{
  width: 0px;
  float:right;
  height: 100%;
}

.bar{
  height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row_outer">
    
    <div class="text">Test Text 78oo76o689o 76o 68k yuk uik</div><div  class="holder"><div class="bar">
    </div></div> 
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank-you.

Comment: For that the most important question is .. **How wide do you want the container to be ?? (excluding the red bar)** You can't expect to have a container which is 100% wide & want the red bar to extend after that 100% & not expecting the scroll to come. So in a way width is "100% + red bar width"(obviously it will bring up the scroll)

Comment: If the *bar* div is supposed to be the full width of the page add `right: 0;` to your rules (and probably change the z-index as well).

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa the bootstrap container is a fixed width.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/6do5bueo/

Comment: Try adding   `right: 0;  top: 0;  z-index: -1;` to your `.bar` rules.

Comment: @vanburen Thank-you! Your answer pushed me in the right direction, this created a bar that went to both sides of the page, i set it to 50% with and it hid the left hand side.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.